# Помогите непонятный PHP код return($var & 1);

Tags: php, битовые-операции

Изучаю PHP функцию `array_filter`, на сайте [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_func_array_filter) наткнулся на непонятный код,

```
function test_odd($var)
{
    return($var & 1);
}

$a1=array("a","b",2,3,4);
print_r(array_filter($a1,"test_odd"));
```

после фильтрации непонятно почему возвращается

```
Array ( [3] => 3 )
```

---

Что делает строка `return($var & 1);` ?

В чем предназначение оператора `&` ?

Если можно ответе *подробно* , потому что это совсем *незнакомый синтаксис*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13358313/6275986

Answer (score 3):

Функция выполняет побитовую операцию. В процедуре проверяется нечетность. Все нечетные числа имеют младший бит `1`, четные числа - `0`. Выполняется `AND` двух числел. Например, `3` представляется как `11` в двоичном коде. `11 & 01 = 01`, `1` это `true`, поэтому число нечетное.